# 500 Internal Server Error for a PHP file on LAMP server

Tags: php

I have a simple code to generate a Captcha image :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $captchanumber = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $captchanumber = substr(str_shuffle($captchanumber), 0, 6);
    $_SESSION["code"] = $captchanumber;
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("bj.jpg");
    $foreground = imagecolorallocate($image, 175, 199, 200); //font color
    imagestring($image, 5, 15, 15, $captchanumber, $foreground);
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($image);
?>
```

On localhost image is generated , on LAMP it gives 500 Internal Error. I checked php.ini setting :

```
 session.save_handler = files
```

Is there any other setting I need to check / change ?

Comment: A 500 error in PHP means _go look in your web server error log_. The error will be detailed there unless you have error_reporting turned off entirely.  Always when developing and testing code, turn up error_reporting and display errors on screen:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your script, or set them correspondingly in php.ini. (but don't display_errors in production)

Comment: Possible (shot in the dark, absent any error message) problems: The GD image extension is not installed. Nothing else about this would cause fatal errors, you don't use any version-specific syntax.